# How to check if latitude and longitude of a specific address belongs to lat and long of a city?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-places-api, google-latitude

I offer to users to create an event at some specific place, I use `Google places API` to auto complete address. So when user types `"New Yor"` it might offer him `"New York, Central Park"`. If he chooses that, the whole address is saved in database + latitude and longitude of the address.

The problem comes now, when another user wants to see all events from the `New York`.

Since service I am using doesn't support wild card search, I am looking for a way to see if `New York` latitude and longitude includes `New York, Central Park` latitude and longitude.

Any idea?

Some code:

```
uri = "https://www.maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(params[0].toString(), "UTF-8") +  
"&sensor=false";
```

Comment: Why not break up the data before you save it, instead of simply saving the whole String? e.g. Split "New York, Central Park" into separate columns of State and Locality, respectively. Then it will be much easier to determine state-wide events, and even events within said state's sub-localities. Saving that whole whole String really only hurts you and will definitely make your job harder when it comes time to actually using the data.

Comment: Very good point actually, thank you. But unfortunately auto complete sometimes offers City + Country and sometimes it also offers address. But yes, I can split it by commas and figure out something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save the results of just the "New York" search, be sure to save the latitude/longitude bounds as well.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new%20york
```

The bounds are in the JSON under results->geometry->bounds

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New York, NY, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
                  "lng" : -73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4913686,
                  "lng" : -74.25908989999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7127837,
               "lng" : -74.0059413
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
                  "lng" : -73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4913686,
                  "lng" : -74.25908989999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now when you want to see if "New York Central Park" is within "New York", do a simple check to see if central park's lat/long is greater than the southwest boundary, but less than the northeast boundary.

Comment: That seems to be an answer! I was thinking about something like that, I just didn't know that is enough to check if it is greater or less. My fault, but thank you :)

Comment: I did a little research concerning the two rare edge cases: when the boundary contains the north/south pole (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=antarctica) and when the boundary contains the 180 degree longitude line (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=alaska). In the former case, Google uses the pole as a boundary point, which works with our simple check. In the latter case, it won't work unless you always first make sure the northeast longitude is greater than the southwest longitude, otherwise add 360 to the northeast longitude to normalize and it works.